# gmp google managed prometheus example not working on a brand new vanilla stable gke autopilot cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, prometheus, google-managed-prometheus

Google managed prometheus seems like a great service however at the moment it does not work even in the example... https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/managed-prometheus/setup-managed

Setup:

- create a new autopilot cluster `1.21.12-gke.2200`
- enable manage prometheus via gcloud cli command
  `gcloud beta container clusters update <mycluster> --enable-managed-prometheus --region us-central1`
- add port 8443 firewall webhook command
- install ingress-nginx
- try and use the `PodMonitoring` manifest to get metrics from ingress-nginx

```
Error from server (InternalError): error when creating "ingress-nginx/metrics.yaml": Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "default.podmonitorings.gmp-operator.gke-gmp-system.monitoring.googleapis.com": Post "https://gmp-operator.gke-gmp-system.svc:443/default/monitoring.googleapis.com/v1/podmonitorings?timeout=10s": x509: certificate is valid for gmp-operator, gmp-operator.gmp-system, gmp-operator.gmp-system.svc, not gmp-operator.gke-gmp-system.svc
```

There is a thread suggesting this will all be fixed this week (8/11/2022), https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/prometheus-engine/issues/300, but it seems like this should work regardless.

if I try to port forward ...

```
kubectl -n gke-gmp-system port-forward svc/gmp-operator 8443
error: Pod 'gmp-operator-67d5fff8b9-p4n7t' does not have a named port 'webhook'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is now fixed, if you have trouble this permalink how to guide includes troubleshooting tips.
It's GMP (google managed prometheus) on GKE Autopilot, I just ran through their examples, and they more or less work.
https://gist.github.com/neoakris/bfc67fef83fecde6384ab4f8afe5fc95